# Удалить все два идущих подряд одинаковых символа из строки

Tags: visual-c++, алгоритм, c++

Мой алгоритм удаляет все одинаковые символы, идущие подряд (друг за другом), а надо только два таких символа удалять. Вот мой код:

```
int main()
{
    string s = "abcccdeee", res;        
    list< char > ls(s.begin(), s.end());
    list< char >::iterator it;
    size_t i, l = s.length();

    for (i = 1; i < l; i++)
    {   
        if (s[i-1] == s[i])
        {
            ls.remove(s[i-1]);
            ls.remove(s[i]);
            continue;
        }       
    }

    res.assign(ls.begin(), ls.end());
    cout << res;

    //выдаёт abd а надо abcde
    //еще пример: abgffgcdeee - на выходе должен быть тотже abcde
    return 0;
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, c реализацией.

Comment: @arammis, это вообще неправильно. 

Рассудите сами. Например для "zz123" Вы удаляете 0-й ('z') и следующий 'z' вообще-то становится уже 0-м символом строки. Причем размер строки (у Вас `l`) уменьшится на 2.

Теперь о [remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove/)

    Removes from the container all the elements that compare equal to val.

Не думаю, что это то, что Вы хотели.

--

IMHO тут можно обойтись и одной строкой, сделайте цикл до .size(), для удаления символов вызывайте .erase(i - 1, 2) а затем (вместо `continue`) пропустите во вложенном цикле такие же символы.

Comment: Это довольно очевидный (для начала) алгоритм.

Конечно, использование .erase() в такой ситуации может быть и не слишком эффективно и вместо него  можно просто копировать символы внутри строки, пропуская удвоенные, а потом скорректировать ее размер.

Comment: @arammis; Вы смогли написать алгоритм, который удаляет _все_ дубликаты, и не можете переписать его, чтобы он удалял только _первый_? Это очень странно.

Comment: ну под конец рабочей недели уже голова не варит, видите ли)) я уже написал верный алгоритм, но это медленно (

Comment: @avp
вот сделал что то похожее на ваши слова - но это очень медленно



    string s;
 cin >> s;

 size_t l = s.length();
 bool stop = false;

 for ( ; !stop ; )
 {
  stop = true;
  for (size_t i = 1; i < l; i++)
  {    
   if (s[i-1] == s[i])
   {    
    s.erase(i-1, 2);   
    l -= 2;
    stop = false;
   }
  }
 }

    cout << s;

но это очень медленно

Comment: @VladD
под конец рабочей недели голова уже немного не соображает

Comment: @arammis, хотел бы уточнить, из "aaaaa" должно получиться "aaa" или "a"?

Comment: ааааа на выходе a

Comment: тоесть удаляем все рядом идущие дупликаты пока строка не станет уникальной

Comment: @avp я выше уже реализовал, но надо побыстрее чтобы работало, есть ли какие-нибудь стандартные алгоритмы, работающие быстрее, чем это?

Comment: @arammis, стандартных функций не знаю, а стандартный чисто сишный подход к делу:


      int i = 0, j = 0, l = s.size();
      while (i < l - 1) {
        if (s[i] != s[i + 1])
          s[j++] = s[i++];
        else
          i += 2;
      }
      if (i < l)
        s[j++] = s[i++];
      
      s.resize(j);
    
думаю, сработает.

Answer (score 1):

Решай я это **на С** (имея **завершающий нуль**) и **in-place** (т. е. собирая **результат в той же самой строке**), я бы использовал следующее наблюдение – удаление из массива одного элемента требует смещения всех последующих на 1 назад, а после нескольких удалений все последующие символы будут смещены на несколько позиций назад (по сравнению с исходной строкой).

Когда нам надо сделать **N удалений**, мы можем сделать их **по отдельности** (под `0` понимается `\0`, под `_` понимается символ, который больше не будет читаться):

```
aacc0
a_cc0
ac_c0
acc0_
ac_0_
ac0__
```

А можем совместить переносы, считая, на сколько в итоге сместится следующий символ следующим простым правилом: когда встречаем пару последовательных одинаковых символов, смещение (`offset`) увеличивается на `1`. И изначально оно `0`. Обход начинаем со второго (!) символа (с индексом `1`) и помним "каким был предыдущий символ". По мере обхода массива спихиваем символы на `offset` назад. В самом начале обхода строки будет спихивание на 0 позиций назад, т. е. не будет сделано ничего. Но дальше...

```
0 -> '\0', символ с кодом 0
       [i, offset, previous]
aacc0  [     начальное     ]
|
aacc0  [1, 0,      'a'     ] <- символ совпал с предыдущим, увеличить offset
 |
ac_c0  [2, 1,      'a'     ]
 ^|
acc_0  [3, 1,      'c'     ] <- символ совпал с предыдущим, увеличить offset
  ^|
ac0__  [4, 2,      'c'     ] <- курсор на нуль-символе, конец
  ^-|
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s = "abcccdeee", res;

    s.push_back('*'); // что бы невыходить 
    s.push_back('*'); // за пределы строки

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size() - 2; i++){
        if (((s[i] != s[i + 1]) || ((s[i + 2] == s[i + 3]) && (s[i] == s[i + 1]) && (s[i + 1] == s[i + 2]))))
            res.push_back(s[i]);
    }

    cout << res << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: за старания спасибо, конечно, но это не то, что мне нужно, для случая  abccbde выдаёт abcbde, а надо ade, то есть надо проходить до тех пор, пока все пары одинаковых не удалятся. Собственно, можно вложенными циклами (как я уже сделал), но это медленно, надо быстро.

Comment: @perfect, возможно, я не до конца понимаю, что имеет в виду ТС, но мне кажется, что в любом случае из `"aa"` должна получаться пустая строка.

А у Вас? 

--

Да и остальные случаи не очевидны.

Comment: @arammis а без циклов никак. У типа string нет такой функции.

Comment: @perfect
может, использовать какие-нибудь вспомогательные структуры данных, стек или списк, но как?!

Comment: @arammis думаю, нет таких функций и у этих контейнеров

Answer (score 0):

Есть два решения (реализованные на Java)

1. используя рекурсию
2. оптимизируя алгоритм

```
package com.jetforcer.services.words;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author michael.shumenko
 */
public class DoubleCharsApp {

  private static final Map<String, String> INCOMING_2_OUTPUT_WORD_MAP;

  static {
    INCOMING_2_OUTPUT_WORD_MAP = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>() {
      {
        put("pizza", "pia");
        put("apple", "ale");
        put("samsung", "samsung");
        put("pizzacoiin", "piacon");
        put("sssaaammmsssuuunnnggg", "samsung");
        put("lllleeeeddddzeppelin", "zlin");
        put("TTThhhiiisssIIIsssVVVeeerrryyyHHHaaarrrdddWWWooorrrddd", "ThisIsVeryHardWord");
        put("opportunity", "rtunity");
        put("possibility", "poibility");
        put("abgffgcdeee", "abcde");
        put("abccbde", "ade");
      }
    };
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<WordConverter> converters = createConverters();
    converters.forEach(wordConverter -> {
      long startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.println("Start testing: " + wordConverter.getPresentableName());

      INCOMING_2_OUTPUT_WORD_MAP.forEach((incomingWord, expectedOutputWord) -> {
        String actualOutputWord = wordConverter.removeDoubleChars(incomingWord);
        String status = "  " + (expectedOutputWord.equals(actualOutputWord) ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILED");
        System.out.println(String.format("%s: Incoming: %s -> Actual: %s, Expected: %s",
          status, incomingWord, actualOutputWord, expectedOutputWord));
      });

      long endMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
      System.out.println("Finished: " + (endMs - startMs) + " ms.\n");
    });
  }

  private static List<WordConverter> createConverters() {
    return Arrays.asList(new RecursionConverterImpl(), new OptimizedConverter());
  }

  private interface WordConverter {

    String getPresentableName();

    String removeDoubleChars(String word);
  }

  private static class OptimizedConverter implements WordConverter {

    /**
     * We assume that word can't contain underscore
     */
    private static final char SKIPPED_CHAR_MARKER = '_';

    @Override
    public String getPresentableName() {
      return "Optimized Converter";
    }

    @Override
    public String removeDoubleChars(String word) {
      char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
      for (int currCharIndex = 0; currCharIndex < chars.length; currCharIndex++) {
        int nextCharIndex = currCharIndex + 1;

        char currChar = chars[currCharIndex];
        char nextChar = chars.length > nextCharIndex ? chars[nextCharIndex] : SKIPPED_CHAR_MARKER;
        if (currChar == nextChar && currChar != SKIPPED_CHAR_MARKER) {
          chars[currCharIndex] = SKIPPED_CHAR_MARKER;
          chars[nextCharIndex] = SKIPPED_CHAR_MARKER;
        }

        detectNewDoubleCharsAfterSkipping(chars, currCharIndex, nextCharIndex);
      }

      StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
      for (char c : chars) {
        if (c != SKIPPED_CHAR_MARKER) {
          buff.append(c);
        }
      }
      return buff.toString();
    }

    private void detectNewDoubleCharsAfterSkipping(char[] chars, int currCharIndex, int nextCharIndex) {
      int prevCharIndex = currCharIndex - 1;
      int nextAfterNextCharIndex = nextCharIndex + 1;

      char prevChar = prevCharIndex >= 0 ? chars[prevCharIndex] : SKIPPED_CHAR_MARKER;
      char nextAfterNext = nextAfterNextCharIndex < chars.length ? chars[nextAfterNextCharIndex] : SKIPPED_CHAR_MARKER;

      if (prevChar == nextAfterNext && prevChar != SKIPPED_CHAR_MARKER) {
        chars[prevCharIndex] = SKIPPED_CHAR_MARKER;
        chars[nextAfterNextCharIndex] = SKIPPED_CHAR_MARKER;
        detectNewDoubleCharsAfterSkipping(chars, prevCharIndex, nextAfterNextCharIndex);
      }
    }
  }

  private static class RecursionConverterImpl implements WordConverter {

    @Override
    public String getPresentableName() {
      return "Recursion Converter";
    }

    @Override
    public String removeDoubleChars(String word) {
      char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
      int wordLength = word.length();
      for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        int nextCharIndex = i + 1;
        if (nextCharIndex < wordLength && chars[i] == chars[nextCharIndex]) {
          return removeDoubleChars(word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(nextCharIndex + 1, wordLength));
        }
      }
      return word;
    }
  }
}
```